# Optimizing return statement in switch cases in java

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have a switch case that return different methods and their configs. Is it possible to return  it after it goes through all the switch cases.

```
    switch (method.getindex())
     {
        case xxx:
        result= new method(new anothermethod1(something.getindex(0), something.getindex(1)), some varibale);
        break;
        case yyy:
        result= new method(new anothermethod2(something.getindex(0), some varibale);
        break;
     }
     retrun result;
```

This needs to changed to return the result after it breaks from the case and should return result according to the case it picks.
should get like this below

```
    switch (method.getindex())
     {
        case xxx:
        break;
        case yyy:
        break;
     }
     return result = new method( new should take the method automatically when it enters into the corresponding case , some variable);
```

Comment: just `return` inside the `case` blocks?

Comment: Im a little confused what you are asking. This code looks like it should work fine? As long aa you initialize a variable before the switch statement...

Comment: i need them in the final return statement as i am returning the same method in both the cases but different parameters.

Comment: It does already return after it beaks from the case. If it was real code, it would run. What is the actual code, and the actual problem?

Comment: Your code should work just fine.

Comment: The return statement should have the result rather than having it in every case statement
         result= new method(need to know what should i do here, some varibale);

Comment: which is what you have right now. Except of course for the type in `retrun`.

Comment: Stop *explaining* what you are trying to achieve, show the code of what you are trying to achieve, maybe we can help in that case. Show the desired code even if it does not compile yet.

Comment: @Emoji so what exactly isnt working?

Comment: Okay, after your edit, i'd recommend using multiple variables for each parameter, and each switch case updating each one

Comment: @JacobB. can you answer the question elaborately.

Comment: I find your question pretty confusing, so sorry let me confuse you: switch statements are evil. They have (almost) no place in good OOP. Their presence is most often a symptom of bad design. In oo you use polymorphism instead. Don't have some external class query status to then make decisions - instead provide different implementations of a base interface and simply invoke methods.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly you would like to do sth like this:

```
<some type of switch result> switch_result;
switch (method.getindex())
{
    case xxx:
        switch_result = new anothermethod1(something.getindex(0), something.getindex(1));
        break;
    case yyy:
        switch_result = new anothermethod2(something.getindex(0));
        break;
}
retrun new method(switch_result, some varibale);
```

Is that correct?

The question is what to put for < some type of switch result>. You need to pick a type that is either:

1. a super class of both anothermethod1 and anothermethod2
2. an interface that's implemented by both anothermethod1 and anothermethod2

There's an additional requirement. "method" has to have a constructor that takes < some type of switch result>. Otherwise it won't work.

Also keep in mind that if a "method" class has constructors for all three types (anothermethod1, anothermethod2 and < some type of switch result>) then in the code above the version for < some type of switch result> will be called.

Here's an example:

```
public class C {
  static class A {}
  static class B {}
  C(A a, int x) { System.out.println("A " + x); }
  C(B b, int x) { System.out.println("B " + x); }
  C(Object o, int x) { System.out.println("Object " + x); }

  public static void main(String...args) {
    Object switch_result = null;
    switch (args.length) {
      case 0:
      switch_result = new A();
      break;
      case 1:
      switch_result = new B();
      break;
    }
    C result = new C(switch_result, 42);
  }
}
```

No matter how many arguments you pass to main it's gonna print "Object 42".

Comment: The above block is what i want but i did not understand how to approach this, can you write up an example code

Comment: If you want your new method to take the method automatically why don't u define the method outside of switch and based on the output of new method you can select the method1 or method2 using switch case??

Comment: Comment has too small limit so I updated the answer with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can put these various `return` statements inside of each `case` and that way you don't need to use `break` keyword at the end of each `case`.

Answer (score 0):

In each case, have a different set of variables, i.e.

```
case xxx:
method1 = new AnotherMethod1(Something.getIndex());
var1 = someVariable;
```

Then outside if the switch statement:

```
return new Method(method1, var1);
```

Hopefully this helps?

Comment: The problem is to change the methods instantaneously  in the return but not the variable